# Java error - java: cannot find symbol - Bubblesort

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I am learning how to code in Java and currently trying to create a simple Bubblesort algorithm. But when i run the program it says `java: cannot find symbol`.

Since im pretty new to this i don't really know what to do about it.

```
    public int[] liste ={5,2,4,9,8,11};
    public int[] sortieren(){

        int unsortiert;
        for(int sortiert = 0; sortiert < liste.length -1; sortiert++){

            if(liste[sortiert] < liste[sortiert+1]){
                continue;
            }

            unsortiert = liste[sortiert];
            liste[sortiert] = liste[sortiert+1];
            liste[sortiert+1] = unsortiert;
            sortieren();
        }
        return  liste;
    }

    public static void  main (String[] args){
        KartenSort bs = new KartenSort();
        int[] array = bs.sortieren();
        for (int b=0;b < array.length; b++){
            System.out.println(sortiert + 1 +":" + array[sortiert]);
        }
    }
```

> Error:(25, 32) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable sortiert
>     location: class KartenSort

and:

> Error:(25, 58) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable sortiert
>     location: class KartenSort

Comment: Here `System.out.println(sortiert + 1 +":" + array[sortiert])` - variable `sortiert` is not defined in your `main` method.

Comment: could you give me a tip on how to exactly do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int b=0;b < array.length; b++){
            System.out.println(sortiert + 1 +":" + array[sortiert]);
        }
```

replace your above code by

```
for (int b=0;b < array.length; b++){
            System.out.println(b + 1 +":" + array[b]);
        }
```

Comment: thanks, turns out i didn't change all the "b"s to "sortiert"